# How can I make Firebase Analytics connect to analytics service using React Native for an Android app?

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-analytics

The problem is, I seem to have all the code in place, the app runs, but firebase.analytics() returns null.  analytics().getAppInstanceId returns an object with 0 and null values.

We’re using RNfirebase 13.1.0, the latest package available, Yarn tells me. (Although when I got to rnfirebase.io there seems to be a 15.0.0 release.)

We’ve correctly created a firebase project and installed the json file downloaded from the project, into the Android Studio project. We’ve correctly modified the gradle files in the Android Studio project.

Everything runs, but no connection, responses return null objects and we cannot log events.

This is our index.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
 import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from "react";
 import App from "./App";
 import { name as appName } from "./app.json";
 
 import { Provider as PaperProvider } from "react-native-paper";
 import { Provider as StoreProvider } from "react-redux";
 import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
 import { ModalsProvider } from "react-native-nested-modals";
 
 import { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/analytics";
 import analytics from "@react-native-firebase/analytics";
 
 import configurePersistentStore from "./src/redux/store/configurePersistentStore";
 
 const { store, persistor } = configurePersistentStore();
 
 export const AnalyticsContext = createContext();
 
 function RNRedux() {
   const [collections, setCollections] = useState();
   const [instance, setInstance] = useState();
   const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState();
 
 
    async function upAnalytics() {
      
       
     setInstance(await analytics().getAppInstanceId());
     console.log("#005 instance id", instance);
 

     

   }
 
   useEffect(() => {
     upAnalytics();
   }, []);
 
   return (
     <StoreProvider store={store}>
       <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
         <PaperProvider>
           <ModalsProvider>
             <AnalyticsContext.Provider value={{collections: collections, instance: instance}}>
               <App />
             </AnalyticsContext.Provider>
           </ModalsProvider>
         </PaperProvider>
       </PersistGate>
     </StoreProvider>
   );
 }
 
 AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => RNRedux);
```

this is where we enable logging in app.tsx (and examine the context variables passed in the Provider) :

```
 useEffect(() => {
     console.log("#002  collections", collections)
     console.log("#003 instance ", instance)

     // we have verified that the instance returned by analytics
     // exists at this point, but all it's object properties are null or zero.
     analytics().setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
     
     
   }, [])
```

and this is how we log an event in a working component (response is always null and event is not logged.)

```
function setUpAnalytics() {
    console.log("#012 setup analytics")
    analytics()
      .logEvent("calculatorView", {
        id: 20000002,
        event: "calculator page",
        description: "whatever",
      })
      .then((response) => console.log("#011 response is ", response))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setUpAnalytics();
  }, []);
```

in app build.gradle:

```
   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:13.1.0'
```

in project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
         
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        
    }
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.xxxx
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "xxxxxxx";
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //SplashScreen.show(this);
    super.onCreate(null);
  }
  
}
```

in the manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

google-services.json is located correctly in the Android project.
(tried to include a pic but SO wouldn't let me upload it, was told it was 'forbidden').

this is our console.log from terminal (I've eliminated some of the testing in the code example to make it clearer, but the 'thisID' is the object returned by getAppInstanceID)

```
 LOG  #008 thisthing [object Object]
 LOG  show thisID  {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
 LOG  #002  collections undefined
 LOG  #003 instance  undefined
 LOG  #007 error [TypeError: undefined is not a function]
 LOG  #005 instance id undefined
```

Comment: Is it possible I configured the wrong app? I'm configuring the app generated by my RN project. But there's also an app in @react-native-firebase/app. Reading the docs on rnfirebase.io, it seems...that's the android app that gets the google-services json file?

Comment: Maybe not. creating a fresh RN app and working with that.